# I want to recreate this quote in css

Tags: css

Hello i am a beginner in css and i want to recreate this:

[image]

this is  my current start,i don`t know how to put the ' " '

```css
#rectangle{
    width: 100%;
 height: 230px;
 background-color:darkcyan;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    
}
#rectangle p{
    padding-top: 85px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: ;
    font-family: roboto_bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: aliceblue
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `:before`, something like this should give you an approximative result

```
#rectangle p:before {
   content: '"';
   position: absolute;
   color: yellow;
   font-size: 2em;
   transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways of doing this, one of which is that you can use icons.
Like I personally use **[fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/)**.

You can get many icons of different sizes just use them with an online css file.

http://fontawesome.io/icon/quote-left/

This is the link to the quotes that you want to insert

I created a prototype for you.

https://codepen.io/djmayank/pen/opYeyo

```css
#rectangle{
    width: 100%;
 height: 230px;
 background-color:darkcyan;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    
}
#rectangle p{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: ;
    font-family: roboto_bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: aliceblue
}
.fa {
  
  color:#abe941;
  margin-top:3%;
  margin-left:10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle">
  <i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <p>Loreim ispum Loreim ispumLoreim ispum Loreim </p>
</div>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/8d594f9226.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner the inclusion of other libraries or pseudo elements may be tricky. Here's a rather straightforward start.

```css
.blue-box {
  background: #2edfd2;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  width: 300px;
}

.lquote {
  color: #ace941;
  font-size: 60px;
  height: 20px;
}

.underline {
  background-color: #ace941;
  height: 4px;
  width: 20px;
}

.fine-print {
  margin: 4px 0 0;
  font-size: .6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-box">
  <div class="lquote">&ldquo;</div>
  <p>Knowing I was adopted may have made me feel more independent, but I have never felt abandoned. My parents made me feel special.
    <div class="underline"></div>
    <p class="fine-print">Steve Jobs, 2009</p>
</div>
```